# jQuery Set Checkbox to be Checked based on 3 conditions data

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Is it possible to check checkbox based on `data-id` and `data-tipe` and `data-group` using jQuery on my case below:

**Updated Question**

```
success: function (jsonStr)
{
    var len = jsonStr.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        var moduleID = jsonStr[i].moduleID;
        var moduleName = jsonStr[i].moduleName;
        var projectName = jsonStr[i].projectName;
        var groupID = jsonStr[i].groupID;
        var chk = jsonStr[i].chk;
        var chkModule = jsonStr[i].chkModule;
        var group = jsonStr[i].group;

        var tr_str = "<tr id='"+jsonStr[i].moduleID+"'>" +
            "<td>" + projectName + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + moduleName + "<input type='text' name='chkTipeInput[]' class='chkTipeInput"+jsonStr[i].moduleID+"'/></td>" +
            "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' data-id='"+jsonStr[i].moduleID+"' data-group='"+jsonStr[i].groupID+"' data-tipe='CREATE' value='CREATE'/></td>" +
            "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' data-id='"+jsonStr[i].moduleID+"' data-group='"+jsonStr[i].groupID+"' data-tipe='EDIT' value='EDIT'/></td>" +
            "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' data-id='"+jsonStr[i].moduleID+"' data-group='"+jsonStr[i].groupID+"' data-tipe='VIEW' value='VIEW'/></td>" +
            "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' data-id='"+jsonStr[i].moduleID+"' data-group='"+jsonStr[i].groupID+"' data-tipe='DELETE' value='DELETE'/></td>" +
            "</tr>";

            $('.dataShow2').show();
            $("#tData tbody").append(tr_str);
    }

    $(":checkbox").each(function() {
       $(this).prop("checked", $(this).attr("data-id") == chkModule && $(this).attr("data-tipe") == chk && $(this).attr("data-group") ==   group )
    })
})
```

Array for:

```
chk       = CREATE,EDIT,  EDIT,  VIEW
chkModule = MD0003,MD0003,MD0002,MD0002
group     = GR0001,GR0001,GR0001,GR0001
```

Means if :

```
if data-id="1" and data-tipe="create" and data-group="a" then check the checkbox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//$(":checkbox").each(function() {

//$(this).prop("checked", $(this).attr("data-id") == 1 && $(this).attr("data-tipe") == "create" && $(this).attr("data-group") == "a")
//})

//var data = [1,"create","a"]//array of values

var chk = ["CREATE", "VIEW", "EDIT", "DELETE"]
var chkModule = ["MD0003", "MD0002", "MD0003", "MD0002"]
var group = ["GR0001", "GR0001", "GR0001", "GR0001"]


for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log(chk[i] + " " + chkModule[i] + " " + group[i])
  $(":checkbox[data-tipe=" + chk[i] + "][data-id=" + chkModule[i] + "][data-group=" + group[i] + "]").prop("checked",true)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Nama</th>
    <th>Create</th>
    <th>Read</th>
    <th>Update</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>coba</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="MD0003" data-tipe="CREATE" data-group="GR0001"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="MD0002" data-tipe="VIEW" data-group="GR0001"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="MD0003" data-tipe="EDIT" data-group="GR0001"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="MD0002" data-tipe="DELETE" data-group="GR0001"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>coba 2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="create" data-group="a"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="read" data-group="a"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="update" data-group="a"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="delete" data-group="a"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" id="btnUpdate" value="Update" />
  </tr>
</table>
```

Use the condition if true then prop == check

Comment: Hi Guradio, how about if the value of data-id, data-tipe and data-group is array? How to do?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave data attribute with array value?

Comment: Yes, all of that 3 data is from array

Comment: @HiDayurieDave can you give sample of that array

Comment: @HiDayurieDave added a simple demo for array values

Comment: Hi guradio, I updated my question above. Please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137307/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-guradio).

Answer (score 2):

You might use a filter

```
$('input[type=“checkbox”]').filter(function() {
 return $(this).data("id") == "1" && $(this).data("tipe") == "create" && $(this).data("group") == "a");
}).prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: Hi Mark, how about if the value of data-id, data-tipe and data-group is array? How to do?

Comment: I don't understand your question in context, the filter looks at all the input checkboxes and checks the box if the data values are true on that one. - if you mean the value compared TO then just reference the array element for each instead of the hard coded value like "1" use `myarray[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify attribute and its value in selector, and then use `prop` for setting property value:

```
$("input[data-id='1'][data-tipe='create'][data-group='a']").prop("checked", true);
```

Demo:

```js
$("input[data-id='1'][data-tipe='create'][data-group='a']").prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Nama</th>
    <th>Create</th>
    <th>Read</th>
    <th>Update</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>coba</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="1" data-tipe="create" data-group="a"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="1" data-tipe="read" data-group="a"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="1" data-tipe="update" data-group="a"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="1" data-tipe="delete" data-group="a"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>coba 2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="create" data-group="a"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="read" data-group="a"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="update" data-group="a"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-tipe="delete" data-group="a"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" id="btnUpdate" value="Update" />
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Yeldar, how about if the value of data-id, data-tipe and data-group is array? How to do?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Hello. How can value of an attribute be an array? :)

Comment: Actually the checkbox is on loop, ask: Am I need to make new question again or enough in this question here?